# ImageMagick: Non-linear stretching an image along one axis

Tags: imagemagick

When downloading images from the METEOR M-2 satellite, the image is compressed near the edges. This is corrected by a windows utility called [SmoothMeteor](https://leshamilton.co.uk/meteor3m.htm). The problem with this app is that it's windows only, and doesn't seem to have a batch mode.

Is it possible to use ImageMagick to stretch an image only along the X axis, so that in the center there is no stretching, but the closer it is near the border, the more stretching is applied?

An example is provided here:
[image]
Notice how the center of the map is largely unaffected but the clouds near the left edge look about 4 times wider than the original.

I would guess this is like a pincushion transformation but only on the X axis, but I'm not sure if I'm even in the right track.

Comment: Have you tried Emailing the author to ask?

Answer (score 2):

What is your platform? If on Unix-like (Linux, Mac OSX, Window 10 Unix or Windows w/Cygwin), then I have a bash shell script calling ImageMagick, called "xpand", that does what you ask.  See my web site at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php

Input:

[image]

```
xpand -d 350 -m horizontal img.png result.png
```

[image]

-d can be either a dimension or an aspect ratio (w:h). I note that my approach (a 2nd order stretch) seems to stretch the result a bit more than your SmoothMeteor tool.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't seem to run this. Tried an image from the satellite (848x1280) and specifying -d 3:2 never finished (100% CPU over 5 minutes), and -d 1480 gives invalid dimension. Here is the image in question https://i.imgur.com/d44Uxq1.jpg and the output from smoothmeteor: https://i.imgur.com/Ytxz691.jpg

Comment: `@hjf`. Sorry, I should have commented, but my script uses the very slow ImageMagick -fx to do the computations and your image is very large. So it will take a very long time to run. I did not realize you had such large images. I ran it on my Mac Mini and it finished in about 2 minutes. You may contact me at my private email address in my link to my web site. I can then send you my result and see why you could not run it. That was with -d 3:2. But your -d 1480 is smaller width than your input (1568x2384). The script does not permit that. Your input is 1568.